# Adding additional Entities to game causes player to move slower

Tags: game-physics, sfml, entities, timedelta

**Warning: Big post, small problem**

I'm trying to use SFML 2.3.2 to make a game, things have been going pretty well. I've got moving platforms, a movable, jumping, colliding player character (albeit a box). And I'm also making things move distance according to time passed instead of according to a locked framerate, but it seems I messed up somewhere.

**The Problem:**

The more Entities I add (boxes for my player character to collide with and moving platforms) the slower the player moves and the lower he jumps, despite using a (deltaTime * movement speed) calculation (The moving platforms seem to be consistent in their movements though, no matter the quantity of Entities)

This is the biggest project I've made up to this point so I'll try my best to give all the relevant information.

So first I'll show the structure of all of the files in my project, that way if there's code that's needed that I left out you can just ask me "Hey, what's in there?". Besides that I'll copy the code that I think is relevant to this problem. Which is code of the Engine(a veeeery basic one), Player, and VelocityModule

**Project Files:**

.h = header file only

.cpp = source file only

.h/.cpp = both header and source files

**Dutchtilities:**

- DutchFunctions.h/.cpp
- ExternalInclusion.h
- gameHeaders.h
- sheepPointer.h

**Entities:**

- Entity.h/.cpp
- MovingPlatform.h/.cpp
- Player.h/.cpp
- Quadrangle.h/.cpp
- EntityPack.h (Collection of all other Entity headers)

**Modules:**

- Module.h/.cpp
- TransformModule.h/.cpp
- HitboxModule.h/.cpp
- DrawModule.h/.cpp
- VelocityModule.h/.cpp
- ModulePack.h (collection of all other module headers)

**System:**

- Engine.h/.cpp
- Level.h/.cpp
- Reader.h/.cpp

I believe the problems are centred around the VelocityModule and the way it updates

**Relevant Code:**

Engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

// Forward Declaration
class Level;
#include "Reader.h"

class Engine
{
public:

    // Functions - System
    bool            update();
    void            initWindow();

    // Functions - Time
    sf::Time        getLastFrameTime();
    void            resetLastFrameTime();

    // Functions - Camera
    void            updateCamera();
    void            setCameraTransform( TransformModule* transform );
    void            setCameraOffset( sf::Vector2f &offset );
    void            setCameraOffset( float x, float y );
    sf::Vector2f    getCameraOffset();

    // Functions - Window
    void            setWindowName( const std::string &name );
    void            setWindowDimensions( sf::Vector2u &widthHeight );
    void            setWindowDimensions( unsigned width, unsigned height );
    sf::Vector2u    getWindowDimensions();

    // Functions - Levels
    void            loadLevel( Level* level );

    // Variables - Camera
    sf::View                camera;

    // Variables - Time
    sf::Clock               clock;
    sf::Time                deltaTime;

    // Variables - Window
    sf::RenderWindow        window;

    // Variables - Reader
    Reader                  fileReader;

    // Structors
    Engine();


protected:

    // Variables - Level
    Level*                      m_level;

    // Variables - Camera
    sheepPtr<TransformModule>   m_cameraTarget;
    sf::Vector2f                m_cameraOffset;

    // Variables - Time
    float                       m_frameTime;

    // Variables - Window
    sf::Event                   m_eventHandler;
    std::string                 m_windowName;
    sf::Vector2u                m_windowDimensions;

    // Variables - Game Loop
    bool                        m_paused;
};

#endif
```

The engine contains 3 functions I believe to be important:

- update() this is the main game loop
- getLastFrameTime()
- resetLastFrameTime()

Engine::update()

```
bool    Engine::update()
{
    this->resetLastFrameTime();

    bool isRunning = true;

    // if the window is open...
    if( this->window.isOpen() )
    {
        // Shortcuts
        Level &level = *(this->m_level);


        // LOOK AT WINDOW EVENTS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Keyboard Events
        while( window.pollEvent( this->m_eventHandler ) )
        {
            // Stop program when X is pressed
            switch( this->m_eventHandler.type )
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                this->window.close();
                isRunning = false;
                break;
            }
            // Pause/Resume game when escape is pressed
            if( this->m_eventHandler.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased &&
                this->m_eventHandler.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            {
                this->m_paused = !m_paused;
                std::string line = (m_paused) ? "Game has paused\n" : "Game has unpaused\n";
                std::cout << line;
            }
        }

        // The main game loop
        if( this->window.hasFocus() &&
            m_paused == false )
        {
            // UPDATE ENTITY HITBOXES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.hitboxUpdateEntities();
            // APPLY VELOCITIES TO TRANSFORMS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.updateVelocities();
            // DETECT COLLISIONS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.resetCollisionLists();
            level.createCollisionLists();
            // APPLY EFFECTS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.updateEntities();
            // ADJUST FOR COLLISION ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.adjustHitboxes();
            // DRAW STUFF /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            level.updateDraws();


            this->updateCamera();
            this->window.display();
            this->window.clear();
        }
    }
    // Otherwise the window has closed
    else
        isRunning = false;

    return isRunning;
}
```

Engine::getLastFrameTime()

```
sf::Time        Engine::getLastFrameTime()
{
    return this->deltaTime;
}
```

Engine::resetLastFrameTime()

```
void            Engine::resetLastFrameTime()
{
    this->deltaTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
    this->clock.restart();
}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player : public Entity
{
public:

    void virtual update() final;
    void virtual hitboxUpdate() final;

    short health;
    float movementSpeed;
    float jumpingPower;

    Player();
    ~Player();


private:

    // Modules
    sheepPtr<TransformModule>   transform;
    sheepPtr<DrawModule>        draw;
    sheepPtr<HitboxModule>      collisionHitbox;
    sheepPtr<HitboxModule>      jumpHitbox;
    sheepPtr<VelocityModule>    velocity;

    bool m_grounded;
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Functions I believe to be important:

- hitboxUpdate()

Player::hitboxUpdate()

```
void Player::hitboxUpdate()
{

    // Calculate the distance the player will move this update
    float distance = (this->movementSpeed * this->m_pEngine->getLastFrameTime().asSeconds() );


    // Jumping (Up)
    if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Space) &&
        this->m_grounded == true)
    {
        this->velocity->addVelocity( sf::Vector2f( 0, -(this->jumpingPower) ));
    }
    // Left
    if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) )
        this->velocity->addVelocity( sf::Vector2f( -distance, 0 ));
    // Right
    else if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D) )
        this->velocity->addVelocity( sf::Vector2f( distance, 0 ));
}
```

VelocityModule.h

```
#ifndef VELOCITYMODULE_H
#define VELOCITYMODULE_H

class VelocityModule : public Module
{
public:
    // Functions - System
    void            update();

    // Functions - Velocity
    void            addVelocity( sf::Vector2f &velocity);
    sf::Vector2f    getVelocity();
    void            setVelocity( sf::Vector2f velocity );
    void            applyVelocity();
    void            setMaxVelocity( float maxVelocity );
    float           getMaxVelocity();
    void            setMinVelocity( float minVelovity );
    float           getMinVelocity();


    // Functions - Drag
    void            setDrag( float dragForce );
    float           getDrag();
    void            setApplyDrag( bool trueOrFalse );
    bool            getApplyDrag();

    // Functions - Gravity
    void            setGravity( float gravity );
    float           getGravity();
    void            setApplyGravity( bool trueOrFalse );
    bool            getApplyGravity();

    // Functions - Transform
    void                setTargetTransform( TransformModule* transform );
    TransformModule*    getTargetTransform();

    // Structors
    VelocityModule();
    ~VelocityModule();

private:
    // Variables - Velocity
    sf::Vector2f            m_velocity;
    float                   m_minVelocity;
    float                   m_maxVelocity;


    // Variables - Drag
    float                   m_dragForce;
    bool                    m_applyingDrag;
    static const float      MAX_DRAG;
    static const float      MIN_DRAG;

    // Variables - Gravity
    float                   m_gravityForce;
    bool                    m_applyingGravity;

    // Variables - Transform
    sheepPtr<TransformModule> m_targetTransform;

};

#endif // VELOCITYMODULE_H
```

VelocityModule functions I believe to be relevant:

- update()
- addVelocity()
- applyVelocity()

  void            VelocityModule::update()
  {

  ```
  // Shortcut frametime
  float seconds = this->m_pParentEntity->getLinkedEngine()->getLastFrameTime().asSeconds();


  // Apply Gravity, if it's enabled
  this->m_velocity.y += ( this->m_applyingGravity ) ? (this->m_gravityForce * seconds) : 0 ;
  // Apply drag, if it's enabled
  this->m_velocity *= ( this->m_applyingDrag ) ? pow( 1 - (m_dragForce/100), seconds ) : 1 ;

  // Shortcutting via calculations
  sf::Vector2f absoluteVelocity = sf::Vector2f(abs(this->m_velocity.x), abs(this->m_velocity.y));
  float maxFrameVel = this->m_maxVelocity * seconds;
  float minFrameVel = this->m_minVelocity * seconds;

  // Change velocities according to maximum and minimum barriers
  this->m_velocity.x = ( absoluteVelocity.x < minFrameVel ) ? 0 :
                       ( absoluteVelocity.x > maxFrameVel && m_velocity.x < 0 ) ? -maxFrameVel :
                       ( absoluteVelocity.x > maxFrameVel && m_velocity.x > 0 ) ? maxFrameVel :
                        m_velocity.x;

  this->m_velocity.y = ( absoluteVelocity.y < minFrameVel ) ? 0 :
                       ( absoluteVelocity.y > maxFrameVel && m_velocity.y < 0 ) ? -maxFrameVel :
                       ( absoluteVelocity.y > maxFrameVel && m_velocity.y > 0 ) ? maxFrameVel :
                        m_velocity.y;


  this->applyVelocity();
  ```

  }

VelocityModule::addVelocity()

```
void            VelocityModule::addVelocity( sf::Vector2f &velocity)
{
    this->m_velocity += velocity;
}
```

VelocityModule::applyVelocity()

```
void            VelocityModule::applyVelocity()
{
    if( m_targetTransform.ptr != nullptr )
    {
        // Shortcutting
        this->m_targetTransform->move( this->m_velocity );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its to do with time and its not just lag? Lag may happen if your collision checking is inefficient.

Comment: Lag in what sense exactly? because when it comes down to framerate, when I have about 3 entities (2 moving platforms and 1 player) engine::update() gets called about 3000 times per second when the player is colliding with one of the platforms, and when the player is mid air (not colloding with any platforms) engine::update gets called about 4500 times per second.
But when I add like 50 entities, it drops down to ~150 updates per second but even when in mid air, when not colliding, the player drops like a snail yet the platforms move normally

Comment: I just tried SFML's inbuild collision checking function, it gives a less reliable update rate than my own. And I can't say that when I apply the function is very efficient (as in I apply it against all other hitboxes present), thought I don't believe that should matter, since the time it takes to do so should be included in deltaTime, which should in turn affect the speed of the player